# Description of car

Tags: mazda, mazda-3

Could someone please tell me what BI and BL mean for Mazda. I have to purchase two front wheel wheel bearings and it’s a 2013 model Mazda 3. But I’m not sure weather that BL and BI is anything important when ordering themJulie

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question @Julie, what are BL and BI in reference to? Is it in a part number, or some other form of identification? Please be more specific.

Comment: These are different "generations" (Mazda's term) of the car. BK was manufactured from 2003-09, BL 2009-13, BM 2013-16, BN 2016-present. But I have no idea what "BI" would be, unless it's a typo Anything earlier than the BK wasn't a "Mazda 3".

Comment: If mine is 2013 model would I then purchase the BL or BM?

Comment: The BM was actually the "2014 model" even though it was launched in mid 2013, so a "2013 model" should be a BL.

Answer (score 2):

These are different "generations" (Mazda's term) of the car. BK was manufactured from 2003-09, BL 2009-13, BM 2013-16, BN 2016-present.

I have no idea what "BI" would be, unless it's a typo. Anything earlier than the BK wasn't a "Mazda 3".

The BM was actually the "2014 model" even though it was launched in mid 2013, so the OP's "2013 model" should be a BL.

Comment: Good answer. Basically, if the OP wants to order parts, just using the year of the car should get her what she needs without worrying too much about the "BL" or "BM" designation.

Comment: That's one advantage of a national car registration system like the UK's. Just type in your registration plate number, and the garage or parts supplier knows *exactly* what car you mean. Much easier than figuring out whether it makes a difference whether it's the GL, GLS, LS, LX, or some other weird model designator!

Comment: In the US we use the VIN for specific model identification. Many auto parts stores/dealerships/insurance companies will look your car up by the VIN. Unfortunately, a 17 digit code isn't easy to remember or transcribe.